# How to map features into [0,-1] or [-1,1] ranges?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scale

In ML we often re scale features, which is what I want to do. I want to rescale my features(or data) to be between [0,-1] and [-1,1] ranges? 
I've read that this equation works, generally which suggests it might not work in all cases. How do I rescale my data to be between [0,-1] and [-1,1]? Is their a easy way to do this in sklearn? Or in Python or numpy?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get z in [-1,0]:

```
z = (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) - 1
```

To get z in [-1,1]:

```
z = 2 * (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) - 1
```

Both equations are valid as long as `xmin != xmax` which should be the case for almost any reasonable data